# How to determine the default value of an R function when an argument can take one value from a possible set of choices? So to recreate a function call

Tags: r, default-arguments

I have a function that I'd like to know its default values. However, the popular answer given in other posts `formals("fun-name")` does not satisfy my need. The reason is that I have a function called `introBox` from the rintrojs package.
The call to formals as follows yields:

```
formals("introBox")
# $...
# 
# 
# $data.step
# 
# 
# $data.intro
# 
# 
# $data.hint
# 
# 
# $data.position
# c("bottom", "auto", "top", "left", "right", 
#   "bottom", "bottom-left_aligned", "bottom-middle-aligned", 
#   "bottom-right-aligned", "auto")
```

I know that the argument data.position takes 1 value from the set of choices, i.e., "bottom", "auto" etc. How can one know what that default value is without looking into the function's internals?

Answer (score 1):

You **can** get the default values of the arguments of a function by using `formals()` only if the author assigned the default values. If you don't, it means the author did not assign any default value for the function argument.

For example,

```
formals(lm)

#$formula
#$data
#$subset
#$weights
#$na.action
#$method
#[1] "qr"
#$model
#[1] TRUE
#$x
#[1] FALSE
#$y
#[1] FALSE
#$qr
#[1] TRUE
#$singular.ok
#[1] TRUE
#$contrasts
#NULL
#$offset
#$...
```

It shows that the default value of `method` argument in `lm()` is `qr`, but there is no default value for `formula`.

We can write a function in R with without assigning any default value to its argument.

```
myfun1 = function(any_letter, any_number) print(c(any_letter, any_number))

myfun2 = function(any_letter = 'a', any_number) print(c(any_letter, any_number))

myfun3 = function(any_letter = 'a', any_number = 3) print(c(any_letter, any_number))
```

Because of the ***lazy evaluation***, no error message will pop up when these functions are created. But the error message will pop up when the function with no default value is called and no value is assigned by the user:

```
#myfun2()
#Error in print(c(any_letter, any_number)) : 
#  argument "any_number" is missing, with no default
#myfun3()
[1] "a" "3"
```

Again, you can find the default values, if any, by using `formals`:

```
formals(myfun2)

#$any_letter
#[1] "a"

#$any_number
```

Edit to mention match.arg

To assign a character vector to a function argument, such as in data.position,  is an efficient way to provide a table of allowed candidate values.  The function internals then uses `match.arg` to check the user's choice and check if it matches the table, and produces an error message if it doesn't match. The Description in match.arg documentation says "match.arg matches arg against a table of candidate values as specified by choices, where NULL means to take the first one." So, in this case, the default for data.position is `bottom` because it is the first value in the character list.

Comment: Yes I know lazy evaluation, but sometimes when reading documentation, as in this particular function `introBox`, data.position argument takes one of many values, I was wondering if there is a way to determine that one value

Comment: Please kindly check my edited answer about this.